# Jquery creacion de un listado ordenado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un texto en html y debo convertirlo en una lista ordenada, yo llego al punto de seleccionar la lista y aparecen los números pero solo consigo que aparezca una lista ordenada de números  1. Como se haría para que sumara cada numero??

```js
$(function() {
$('span.texto').wrap("<ol><li></li></ol>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<span class="texto">texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto</span>
<span class="texto">texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto</span>
<span class="texto">texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto</span>
<span class="texto">texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto</span>
```

Debería aparecer:

```
1.texto,texto,texto,texto,texto
2.texto,texto,texto,texto,texto
3.texto,texto,texto,texto,texto
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seria de esta manera entonces...

el problema es que al usar: `.wrap("<ol><li></li></ol>");` esta creando una lista individual para cada elemento. y lo que quieres es meter todos los elementos en un Lista.

```js
$(function() {
 $('span.texto')
 .wrapAll('<ol></ol>')
 .wrap('<li></li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<span class="texto">texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto</span>
<span class="texto">texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto</span>
<span class="texto">texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto</span>
<span class="texto">texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto</span>
```

Comment: Esta respuesta ha sido justo la que necesitaba muchas gracias!!! ya no sabia como arreglarlo!!!!

Answer (score 2):

*Eso pasa porque estás haciendo que a cada elemento lo envuelvan 2 etiquetas la **ol** y **li** por independientes. Lo que debes hacer es que a todos los elementos span los envuelva el **ol** y a cada elemento span lo envuelva **li***

*te comparto un ejemplo de como deberías tenerlo*

```js
$(function() {
  $('span.texto').wrap("<li></li>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
<ol>
  <span class="texto">texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto</span>
  <span class="texto">texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto</span>
  <span class="texto">texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto</span>
  <span class="texto">texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto,texto</span>
</ol>
```

*Espero te sirva*

Comment: el ejemplo de ella los span no esta dentro de una etiqueta ol; asique toca reconstruir todo...

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Jorge, pero no podia modificar el html

Comment: vale tranquilo, la respuesta del otro es totalmente válida también